# PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets have no effect

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt5, qwebview

im using a Python 2.7 build of PyQt5 (5.6) and QWebKit was Replaced by
[QtWebEngineWidgets](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html#module-PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets)

Converting the code to QtWebEngineWidgets have no effect, and app do not show, any ideas.

With new QtWebEngineWidgets

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wv = QWebEngineView()
wv.load(QUrl(sys.argv[1]))
wv.show()
app.exec_()
```

the old WebKit

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wv = QWebView()
wv.load(QUrl(sys.argv[1]))
wv.show()
app.exec_()
```

UPDATE!

It seems that QtWebEngineWidgets needs QtWebEngineProcess.exe and added to system PATH found in QT\bin folder or PyQt5 folder.

Also Folders

resources(with icudtl.dat)

translations(with qtwebengine_locales and more)

Have to be copied from respective Qt win version to python folder , in my case.

```
C:\Python27\python-qt5\PyQt5\resources
```

and

```
C:\Python27\python-qt5\PyQt5\translations
```

After that app shows However webpage dont show in app in this example.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wv = QWebEngineView()
wv.load(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39329523"))
wv.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. How are you running the script? What platform are you on? Have you checked that the `QtWebEngineWidgets` module is installed?

Comment: I have updated the Question with some more information.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need Python 3. Your last code sample has worked fine:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wv = QWebEngineView()
wv.load(QUrl("https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5"))
wv.show()
app.exec_()
```

as you can see (changed URL to pip PyQt5 download page):

[image: screenshot from running program]

I'm running Python 3.5, bitness 64, Miniconda edition.